# Interact: spawn id exp0 not open?

Tags: linux, expect

i tried to use simply `interact` as well and also this by removing the last expect staement

```
    expect -re "$prompt"
    send -- "exit\r"
```

with

```
 interact {
     -re "$prompt"
      { send -- "show vlan id 121\r" }
         }
```

i just want to pass the control to the user to do somtheing manually and when he exits thes rest of the loop continues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exit from `interact` user should provide it some command, so it knows when to stop interactive session. For example:

```
expect -re "$prompt"
send -- "show vlan id 121\r"
send_user "To exit interactive mode press Ctrl+C\n"
interact \003 return
send "show ip int br | ex una\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\n"; exit 0
```